# Is there a way to make my script a library so I don't have to import from a specific path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have Python scripts that contain many functions that are used by many other scripts and codes in my program. They do it with `import`.

Today, I was trying to do an import from a different directory, and tried at first this

```
from .etc.mycodes.helper_functions import graph
```

So I tried something like

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/etc/mycodes/helper_functions')
import graph
```

and it did not work either.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do and if it was possible to make my helper_functions some sort of library, so I do not have to specify the path to it, kind of make it a environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your `helper_functions` into a Python package that you can install with `pip install`. See the documentation on [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). It's generally used for distributing Python projects over PyPi for sharing with other developers, but it can also be used for personal or project-specific libraries.

Setup your `my_helper_functions` to be a [Python package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-the-package-files):

> ### Creating the package files
>
> You will now create a handful of files to package up this project and
>   prepare it for distribution. Create the new files listed below - you
>   will add content to them in the following steps.
>
> ```
> packaging_tutorial/  
>   example_pkg/  
>     __init__.py  
>   tests/  
>   setup.py
>   LICENSE
>   README.md
> ```

Then you can just

```
$ cd my_helper_functions
$ pip install .
```

to install it into your Python environment. The `.` here means "install the contents of this folder".

Then in your codes

```
from my_helper_functions import my_awesome_util
```

which doesn't need setting any paths.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to a directory and store your personal import libraries in that directory.